# Problema con un bucle infinito para controlar un DHT11

Tags: c, arduino, sensor, pic, microcontrolador

Me estoy haciendo una maceta autorregable como parte de la domotizacion de mi casa, y para leer la temperatura y humedad, estoy teniendo problemas. Estoy usando un PIC18f4550 con MPLAB X IDE. Para el control del sensor estoy usando una libreria de un chaval de Youtube al que le funcionaba bien, pero a mi se me traba en un bucle y no he encontrado manera de pasar de ahí.

La libreria:

```
/* #include "dht11.h"
*
* Creada por: Ing. Abiezer Hernandez O.
* Fecha de creacion: 10/11/2020
* Electronica y Circuitos
*
*/

#include "dht11.h"

void DHT11_Start(void)
{
    DHT11_PIN_DIR = 0;
    DHT11_PIN_LAT = 0;
    __delay_ms(20);
    DHT11_PIN_LAT = 1;
    __delay_us(30);
    DHT11_PIN_DIR = 1;
}

void DHT11_Response(void)
{
    while(DHT11_PIN_PORT == 1);
    while(DHT11_PIN_PORT == 0);
    while(DHT11_PIN_PORT == 1);
}

int DHT11_Read_Byte(void)
{
    int i,data = 0;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        while((DHT11_PIN_PORT) == 0);
        __delay_us(30);
        if((DHT11_PIN_PORT) == 1){
            data = ((data<<1) | 1);
        }else{
            data = (data<<1);
        }
        while((DHT11_PIN_PORT) == 1);
    }
    return data;
}

short DHT11_Read_Data(float *tem, float *hum)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int info[5];
    DHT11_Start();
    DHT11_Response();
    info[0] = DHT11_Read_Byte();   // Humedad entero
    info[1] = DHT11_Read_Byte();   // Humedad decimal
    info[2] = DHT11_Read_Byte();   // Temp entero
    info[3] = DHT11_Read_Byte();   // Temp decimal
    info[4] = DHT11_Read_Byte();   // Paridad
    *hum = (float)((DHT11_Join_Data(info[0], info[1])) / 10.0f);
    *tem = (float)((DHT11_Join_Data(info[2], info[3])) / 10.0f);
    temp = info[0] + info[1] + info[2] + info[3];
    if(temp == info[4]){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
   }
}

unsigned DHT11_Join_Data(unsigned h, unsigned l)
{
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(l >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return h * pow + l;        
}
```

El bucle se trabaría en esta parte:

**while(DHT11_PIN_PORT == 0);**

La configuración de mi PIC para las entradas y salidas es esta:

```
    //Configuracion inicial ADC
    //ADCON0:
        //Canal   --> AN0
        //GO/DONE --> A/D idle
        //ADON    --> modulo deshabilitado
    ADCON0 = 0b00000000;
    //ADCON1:
        //V- = Vss
        //V+ = Vdd
        //AN0 como analogica, el resto digital
    ADCON1 = 0b00001110;
    //ADCON2
        //Justificacion derecha
        //2 veces el tiempo de adquisicion
        //oscilador interno
    ADCON2 = 0b10001111;
    //Encendemos el ADC
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
    
/*********Entradas**********************************/
    TRISAbits.RA3 = 1;
    TRISBbits.RB0 = 1; 
/*********Salidas***********************************/
    TRISAbits.RA2 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB3 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB4 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB5 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB7 = 0;
    TRISBbits.RB6 = 0;
    //Limpiamos las salidas
    LATAbits.LA2 = 0;
    LATBbits.LB3 = 0;
    LATBbits.LB4 = 0;
    LATBbits.LB5 = 0;
    LATBbits.LB6 = 0;
    LATBbits.LB7 = 0;
```

Comment: Es mala idea usar programación de registros para manejar lo que sea. En esta aplicación en particular, no ganas nada. Haz caso a la respuesta de Mateo.

Answer (score 2):

No sé que tutorial estarás siguiendo. Yo usé [está librería](https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library) sin problemas.

En el repositorio hay algunos ejemplos, pero aquí te dejo uno más simple:

```
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define FAHRENHEIT false

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
  dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
  float temperatura = dht.readTemperature(FAHRENHEIT);
  float humedad = dht.readHumidity();
}
```

Como puedes ver necesitas construir una variable de tipo `DHT` que recibe como primer parámetro el pin al que está conectado y como segundo el tipo de sensor DHT.

Antes de poder leer la información necesitas inicializar la comunicación con el DHT. Para eso llamas al método `begin`.

Posteriormente lees la temperatura en grados centígrados con `dht.readTemperature(false)` y la humedad de 0 a 100% con `dht.readHumidity()`.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero lo estoy haciendo con C y creo que la librería que me has facilitado tu es de C++. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: @LuisBedia aprovechando que funciona y es de código abierto puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Si no te gusta la idea, al menos puedes examinar el código para saber cómo se efectúa la comunicación. A mí me resulta más fácil entender el código que la hoja de datos. Puedes preguntarme si no entiendes algo. Para eso podrías ir al [chat] así no generamos ruido en los comentarios.